# Copy subtotal with fixed range to other table cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtotal

In Excel, I have the following formula:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9;INDIRECT("D$"&$B$2&":D$"&$B$3))
```

It counts the values of a range, which size is defined in other fixed table cells.

- B2 = starting point = 9
- B3 = end point = 17

So in short:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9;D9:D17)
```

I now want to copy that formula to other cols in the same row, I want to pull it to the right (I don't know how that feature is called in Excel). How can I achieve, that only `D` changes to `E` and then to `F` and so on, by the base of my formula? The size of the range should remain the same and has to be linked to table cells B2 and B3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally better to use `INDEX` rather than `INDIRECT` in these type of formulas. One advantage is that the formula **can** be dragged across....try this version

`=SUBTOTAL(9;INDEX(D:D;$B$2):INDEX(D:D;$B$3))`